# Define and inject enum beans in spring

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have some codes as below:

## 1. ConsignmentChartsController Class :

```
public class ConsignmentChartsController extends DefaultWidgetController {
    @Autowired
    private PieChartRenderer  pieChartRenderer;
}
```

## 2. PieChartRenderer interface and DefaultPieChartRenderer class

```
public interface PieChartRenderer {
    void render(Charts chart, final Map<String, Number> chartData);
}
public class DefaultPieChartRenderer implements PieChartRenderer {
   @Autowired
   private List<ChartColor> colors;
    ...........
   @Required
   public void setColors(final List<ChartColor> colors) {
     this.colors = colors;
   }
    
}
```

## 3. Enum class:

```
public enum ChartColor {
   PURPLE() {
      @Override
      public Color getColor() {
         return (new Color("rgba(218,114,218,1)"));
      }
   },
   BLUE() {
      @Override
      public Color getColor() {
        return (new Color("rgba(114,166,218,1)"));
      }
    },
    public abstract Color getColor();
    
    }
```

I want to define these beans on `spring.xml` file. How can I define `ChartColor` bean then inject it to `DefaultPieChartRenderer`, and define `DefaultPieChartRenderer` bean and inject in to `ConsignmentChartsController`?

Comment: ChartColor is an enum, not a bean.. Is just a static value which assists in providing friendly names. You can just use the Enum in the desired class.

Comment: @Kenneth Clark: You right. I have resolved my problem! Thanks!